# What is the file that the websile loads when access?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to fix some problems in a company's website but I dont know where is the main file of the website.
Inside public_html folder there isn't a index.html file (or any other .html) only a index.php (that I will show below) and a lot of folders. I want to do a simple change in the main website index.html (or the .html that the website loads when u access). How can I find it?

This is the index.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Comment: If you don't have ecperience with laravel, you can read the documentation about this framework.

Comment: It looks like there isn't an `index.html`. That PHP file is the entry point. If you don't understand it and want to edit the site, then you are going to have to learn the basics (at least) of PHP.

Comment: There most likely is no ``index.html`` file, todays web sites are created in a dynamic manner, they do not consist of static html files.

Comment: Here is your next file to check. `require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';`. Usually php projects running on an MVC framework have all requests marshalled through `public/index.php`

Comment: IT depends on the change you want to make to know in which file you will need to change. You need to learn laravel before that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using laravel version const VERSION = '5.4.36'; then you can get the main file

public_html/routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
```

});

check the / calling to where

Answer (score 0):

Laravel have it's index inside public folder: public/index.php